# fscanf() only reading in one record, and ignoring the rest

Tags: c

I am reading in records, using fscanf and using a while condition to test that it's reading in expected number of inputs. However, It stops reading in new records after it has read the first one. I can't seeem to put my finger on it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
//STRUCTURE
typedef struct{
    char name[20];
    int age;
    float highBP;
    float lowBP;
    float riskFactor;


    } patient; 

    patient *pRecords[29];
    int counter = 0;
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{




int i=0;
for(;i<30;i++){

    pRecords[i] = (patient *)malloc(sizeof(patient));

}
FILE *fp;
fp = fopen("data.dat", "r");

if(fp == NULL){

    printf("cannot open file\n\n");
return 1;
}


    while(fscanf(fp, "name:\t%s\nage:\t%d\nbp:\t%f %f\nrisk:\t%f\n\n", pRecords[counter]->name, &pRecords[counter]->age, &pRecords[counter]->highBP, &pRecords[counter]->lowBP, &pRecords[counter]->riskFactor) == 5){
    //printf("%d\n",fscanf(fp, "name:\t%s\nage:\t%d\nbp:\t%f %f\nrisk:\t%f\n\n", pRecords[counter]->name, &pRecords[counter]->age, &pRecords[counter]->highBP, &pRecords[counter]->lowBP, &pRecords[counter]->riskFactor));

    printf("%s\n", pRecords[counter]->name);
    printf("%d\n", pRecords[counter]->age);
    printf("%f\n", pRecords[counter]->highBP);
    printf("%f\n", pRecords[counter]->lowBP);
    printf("%f\n", pRecords[counter]->riskFactor);
        counter++;
    }

}
```

data.dat

```
name:   hank
age:    32
bp:     32.00 32.00
risk:   0.0

name:   tom
age:    21
bp:     121.00 81.00
risk:   2.0

name:   cindy
age:    32
bp:     190.00 900.00
risk:   5.0
```

Comment: Check `fscanf` return code. And it seems there is more than just one `tab` after `bp` in second and third record.

Comment: I have checked the formatting, the tab positions are correct.

Answer (score 2):

You define an array with space for 29 elements

```
patient *pRecords[29];
```

and then proceed with assigning values to 30 elements.

```
for(;i<30;i++){

    pRecords[i] = (patient *)malloc(sizeof(patient));

}
```

**Don't do that!** Anything can happen, including the behaviour you describe.

*Also, don't cast the return value of `malloc()`. It is redundant at best and may hide an error the compiler would have caught in the absence of the spurious cast.*

---

I like to use information the compiler already knows for loops and malloc and stuff

```
patient *pRecords[29];
for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof pRecords / sizeof *pRecords; i++) { /* 1 */
    pRecords[i] = malloc(sizeof **pRecords);                      /* 2 */
}
```

- line /* 1 */: `sizeof pRecords / sizeof *pRecords` is the number of elements (pointers) in the array
- line /* 2 */: `sizeof **pRecords` is the size of each (dereferenced) element

Comment: I don't see how I am allocating memory for 30 records, I have i=0;i<30;i++ ?

Comment: In `for (i = 0; i < 2; i++)` the loop will execute twice: once with `i` being 0, another time with `i` being 1. In your loop, `i` will vary from 0, 1, 2, ..., 28, 29 for a count of 30 times through the loop